# How to select several ranges and put them in clipboard using Excel vba?

Tags: vba, excel

I need to select several ranges in `Excel` file using `VBA` and then copy them inside clipboard and then paste them inside text editor. I record several macros - each for each range. But in this case I need to run first macro and then paste, then second and so on. This is very time consuming. Is there a way to select first range and paste inside clipboard, then add next range inside clipboard?

I suppose I can collect all selections inside a var and then paste, but I don't play with `VBA` and I am not aware of the objects that I have to use.

My code looks:

```
Sub step01_Select_DB_Structure()
' Select DB structure and copy into memory
    Range("GF4:GG1000").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
End Sub

Sub step02_Select_UK_Index()
' Select UK column
    Range("GH4:GH1000").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
End Sub

Sub step03_Select_PK_Index()
' Select PK column
    Range("GI4:GI1000").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
End Sub

Sub step04_Select_FK_Index()
' Select FK column
    Range("GJ4:GJ1000").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
End Sub

Sub step05_Select_Others()
' Select Other columns
    Range("GK4:GP1000").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
End Sub
```

**EDIT:**

I my case I need the ranges to be paste in `Clipboard` in the same order one after another, because I use `Excel` for creating formulas and if I try to paste whole range the result is not valid.

Comment: not sure this helps, but if the destination is a text editor, why not put them inside a *.TXT file and then open with the editor. I think it would be easyer than messing around with the clipboard.

Comment: Sure, @PatrickLepelletier, but I am new to VBA for excel and I don't know how to do that. Anyway, the idea is fine. I try to Google about it. 10x for suggestion. Other option is to have string variable and send it to clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Union to combine several areas of ranges in to single Range object

```
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Union(Range("A1:A3"),Range("B6:B9"))
    rng.Copy
```

However in your case it look like you want to copy single area range, i.e. GF4:GP1000. There is no need of Union at all

Comment: Can you provide example?

Comment: I can not copy it as one. Those are formulas and I must have them one after another. This is not working - it is calculated as the big range. This in my case it not OK.